# How the controllers work in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading

I need a counter in the server which holds the number of http requests it received.As each server can handle multiple requests asynchronously (lets say the same controller is being called by every user) at a specific point of time, where can I place the counter so that it can be shared between every request made.

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out? Learning is about doing. Don't ask a question until you're stuck.

Comment: Yes.If you want to share data between multiple requests, you should consider some sort of persisting mechanism like session or a database storage or static/singleton etc

Comment: You have four questions in one. Read [ask] and try searching first, and ask one question per question.

Comment: I reworded the question,Does it require more refinement? @CodeCaster

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the controller is instantiated and disposed with each request. Yes, each request gets it own thread, though that thread may be exchanged (in the case of async work) or may serve multiple requests over its lifetime.

Parallelism is a complex topic and based on numerous different factors at any give time. Simplistically though, yes, threads will run in parallel. However, they do not share resources between each other (for the most part). Ultimately, there is some resource-sharing via the parent process, but for practical application, you should consider them idempotent.

Based on all that and your final question, if you have designs on trying to implement a counter in your code, don't. It won't work and never will. Even if you can somewhat coordinate some sort of process-bound thread-safe counter, it won't work with workers and it will be killed every time the App Pool recycles, crashes or otherwise restarts for any reason.

A counter should be implemented in a database or other persistent data store. Full-stop. Even then, you'll need to be extremely careful with concurrency, and unless you devote a ton of time to excluding bots, repeat page loads by the same users, etc., your count will be off no matter what.